# Inverse Laplace Transform of zero

Tags: laplace-transform

How to prove that the inverse Laplace Transform of zero is zero itself?

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{0\}=0$$

I know that the inverse Laplace Transform of a constant is Dirac's Delta. But I think that that applies only to positive constants.

Thanks

Comment: for any constant $ L^{-1}{C}= C\delta (x) $ if $ c=0 $ we have $0 \delta (t) =0 $ except for the case $ t=0 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{L}(f) = F$, then $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F) =f$. $\mathcal{L}(0) = 0$ because $\mathcal{L}$ is a linear operator.  Or you can actually compute $\mathcal{L}(0)$ using the definition.