# Proving $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(0) =0$ by definition of the Laplace transform.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have seen a proof of $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(0) =0$ here: [Inverse Laplace Transform of zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359329/inverse-laplace-transform-of-zero/360005#360005), but I would like to prove it by definition.

We have $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt=0$. Here, I would like to say that this implies that $e^{-st}f(t)=0$, and since $e^{-st}\neq0$, we have that $f(t)=0$.

However, I'm struggling with justifying that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=0$ implies $f(x)=0$.

I have tried to think of functions that have the same "positive" and "negative" area under the graph for $x \in [0, \infty)$, and I have only been able to think of $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$, for which the integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ is not defined, so my intuition tells me that $f(x)$ should indeed be indentically $0$.

Is my implication correct? Why/ why not?

Comment: You need to use that it’s zero for all s

Comment: Your intuition there doesn’t work because you can just consider sin times an indicator of [0,2pi]

Comment: [This](http://www.ctr.maths.lu.se/media/MATC12/2013ht2013/uniqueness.pdf) should answer your question

Comment: @SolubleFish It did, thank you!